# Java - Function/Method That Accepts BOTH Scalar and Vector Arguments?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, methods, arguments

Say I've got an equation:

```
out = Math.exp(x);
```

where `x` is a `double`.

Say I do it 10,000 times, so I throw it in a function:

```
public double doMath(double x) {
    return Math.exp(x);
}
```

Easy enough. I can pass any scalar to it:

```
double in = 1.1234;

out = doMath(in);

// Outputs something like: 1.1313368652
```

But attempting to pass a vector to it (1D array, 2D array, and so on...) causes all sorts of problems:

```
double[] in = {0.1234, 5.6789};

out = doMath(in);

// Outputs something like: IT DOESN'T OUTPUT! CRASH CRASH CRASH!
```

What I'd like is to be able to pass in any double (scalar, 1D, 2D, 3D, etc) and return the same size as the input, after passing it through the equation, applying the arithmetic to each element.

**Test Cases**

```
double in = 0.1234;

/*
1.1313368652
*/

double[] in = {0.1234, 5.6789};

/*
[ 1.1313368652, 292.6273627191 ]
*/

double[][] in = {{0.1234, 5.6789}, 
                 {0.9876, 5.4321}};

/*
[ [ 1.1313368652, 292.6273627191 ]
  [ 2.6847832542, 228.6288622608 ] ]
*/

double[][][] in = {{{0.1234, 5.6789}, {0.9876}}, 
                   {{5.4321}}, 
                   {{0}, {1}}};

/*
[ [ [ 1.1313368652 292.6273627191 ] [ 2.6847832542 ] ]
  [ [ 228.6288622608 ] ]
  [ [ 1 ] [ 2.7182818285 ] ] ]
*/
```

The only way I have right now is using [overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading):

```
public double doMath(double x)

public double[] doMath(double[] x)

public double[][] doMath(double[][] x)

public double[][][] doMath(double[][][] x)
```

But this is tedious. Can a single function be written to take in any dimension of argument, and return something similar to the examples I've provided?

Maybe there is a name for this, and I just don't know? These are all just arrays, but I'm treating them (and doing other operations on them) as though they were matrices of varying dimensions.

**Edit #1 - Additionally...**

I tried something like:

```
public double doMath(int... x)
```

And it worked for scalar and 1D, but nothing with higher dimensions.

**Edit #2**

Is it possible to write a custom class, that automatically handles this for multiple functions?

For example, say I've got three different functions:

```
public mysteryClass firstFunct(mysteryClass x) {
    return Math.pow(x, 2);
}

public mysteryClass secondFunct(mysteryClass x) {
    return Math.exp(x);
}

public mysteryClass thirdFunct(mysteryClass x) {
    return (1 + x) / 2;
}
```

And each function can be used - *as is* - with any number of dimensions? `mysteryClass` would then automatically recursively run each element through the functions, without having to modify the functions or loop through each element manually? Not sure if it is possible for an object to *know* how it is being used, and adjust accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not polymorphism.  It's overloading.

Comment: @ajb thanks, made the change.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a built-in way to do this, but I got something to work like this:

```
public static Object applyAll(Object x) {
    if (x instanceof Double) {
        return doFunc((Double) x);
    }
    else if (x instanceof Object[]) {
        List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object element : (Object[])x) {
            result.add(applyAll(element));
        }
        return result.toArray(new Object[0]);
    }
    else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected class: " + x.getClass());
    }
}
```

`applyAll` works on either a `Double` or an array, and if it's an array, it calls itself recursively on the elements and builds a result array.  The end result is that the array structure of the final result matches the structure of the outermost argument.  However, if any element is something other than a `Double` or array, it throws an exception.  `doFunc` is a method that accepts a `double` or `Double` argument, and returns a `double` or `Double`.  You could easily pass the function as an argument (using a Java 8 functional interface) instead of requiring `doFunc` to be defined.  In your example, `doFunc` would return `Math.exp` on its argument.

This may not be the best code, but it works.  You don't really need to build a list and then convert to an array, because the size of the array will already be known.  However, I didn't try refining it.  You're free to improve or modify this as needed.

Comment: I don't see why.  I probably didn't understand the problem correctly, and thought the arguments could be mixed like `{1.0, {2.0, 3.0}, 4.0}`; my code handles this case, but it may not be necessary.  But this answer also handles an unlimited number of dimensions.  Even if the requirements are that it has to be an n-dimensional array and `n` is fairly small (e.g. <= 3), I don't see why you'd object to this answer.  Any performance hit from making it more general is bound to be very slight.

Comment: What do you mean by "you still need to implement a case for each number of dimensions"?  This code works on n-dimensional arrays of any degree.

Comment: Who down-voted? Could you please say *why* you did, to help those of us that don't see the same thing you do?

Comment: @ajb I'm trying out your answer now, but I've added an **Edit** to my question, if you want to take a look at it? Basically a more general, all-in-one case.

Answer (score 2):

```
class IncompatibleMultiDoubleException extends RuntimeException {
}

class MultiDouble {
  private double[] data;
  private int[] dims;

  public MultiDouble(int...dimensions) {
    dims = dimensions;
    int tot = 1;
    for (int d : dimensions) {
      tot *= d;
    }
    data = new double[tot];
  }

  // multiply matrix by value
  void cMul(double c) {
    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      data[i] *= c;
    }
  }

  // add two matrices together
  void add(MultiDouble other) {
    for(int i=0; i<other.dims.length; i++) {
      if (dims[i] != other.dims[i]) {
        throw new IncompatibleMultiDoubleException();
      }
    }
  }
  // return the index in the data array corrisponding to the
  // given multidim coordinates
  private int index(int...coords) {
    int res = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<coords.length; i++) {
      int tmp = coords[i];
      for(int j=i+1; j<coords.length; j++) {
        tmp *= dims[j];
      }
      res += tmp;
    }
    return res;
  }

  public void set(double value, int...coords) {
    data[index(coords)] = value;
  }

  public double get(int...coords) {
    return data[index(coords)];
  }
```

Comment: With the 1D array you set up (`double[] data`), it is extremely difficult to do something like `A*B` (matrix multiplication), when the columns and rows aren't clearly defined.

Comment: why? the constructor receives and stores all the dimensions, so all operations can use that information to map indices on the various dimensions into the index in the array. I can add the code for bidim. multiplication if needed

Comment: @Birrel it's not really difficult.  If you represent a 2D array _A_ with _r_ rows and _c_ columns as a 1D vector _V_ with _rc_ elements, then you access `A[m,n]` by accessing `V[cm+n]`.  In languages with true multi-dimensional arrays (Java is not one of those), that's how 2D arrays are handled by the compiler (and it generalizes to multi-dimensional arrays).

Comment: I added the setter and getter and index function for clarity.